# Unable to upgrade apk on my device

Tags: android

I've looked as far as I can here and haven't found a solution that works for me. I've been developing an app using Eclipse and installing the debug version to my device for testing and everything has been working fine. Recently I started working on my laptop, again in Eclipse, and I set my workspace to a network share on the original computer. Everything still worked fine with the emulator but now when I try and install the apk it just says "Application not installed". I'm thinking it has something to do with a certificate but I'm not very knowledgeable in such things. Any help would be great!

Comment: Are you using the same keystore?  Does it work if you uninstall first?

Comment: i don't know anything about keystore...so maybe? i'm pretty sure it will work if i uninstall and reinstall, but i don't want to lose my database info if i do that :s

Comment: Why don't you backup your database, unistall, reinstall and push the database then ? It's easy if your phone is rooted and doable even if it is not.

Comment: i thought about that too but my device isn't rooted and that seems to me more like a workaround than a solution, cause if i switch back and forth from pc to laptop i would have to do that every time.

Comment: If you are relying on data, in a database, which only exists in the app installed on your phone, then you are asking for trouble!  Put the keystore in your Dropbox and set it's location in settings to point to it.  Then you can build anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your new `.apk` is signed with a new `Keystore` and you have installed the same app signed with a different `Keystore` you will get this problem, just delete the installed app and try to install again.

To locate the default keystore path, in Windows:

```
/Users/<username>/.android/debug.keystore.
```

Copy that keystore file and replace it into your laptop´s kestore.

Comment: thanks i thought that might be it but i'm leery about uninstalling it because i don't want to lose my database info

Comment: ups well in that case you need yo sign with the same keystore of the installed app. =)

Comment: i'm not super familiar with that...how would i do that if my laptop is using a different keystore than my pc?